# How can I acheive this transformation in google sheets?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

[image]

I want the rows on the left to be transformed into the one on the right (by splitting on a comma) ,
Actual data contains thousand of such rows, how can I do it easily?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search / research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
={A1:D1; ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(C2:C, ","))="",,
 A2:A&"♀"&B2:B&"♀"&SPLIT(C2:C, ",")&"♀"&D2:D)), 
 "where Col1 is not null"), "♀"))}
```

[image: 0]